# Most innocuous package to install to test yum?

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to test yum is working in CentOS from a local repo. To do this I need a package that:

1. Isn't already installed with standard OS install
2. Is small in size
3. Has few or no dependencies
4. Doesn't affect everyday operation of OS or perform anything in the
   background
5. Is available in the standard repo

So what package could I yum that would meet these criteria?

Comment: Why not just test using something that you actually need?  Then you do not waste bandwidth, and any side-effects or implications are things you would have to live with in any case.

Answer (score 7):

#### edit

This package is not available in the basic repo. but in the forge repo. Though I still think it's a very good package

#### edit

You could just install a devel package like `openssl-devel` or `glibc-devel` those package only include header and will not hurt

I would install `htop` it's a simple binary that enhanced the `top` command experience by 1000 it's less than 1MB and all dependency should be already on your system.

Comment: This would require the rpmforge repo. I will add that I need the standard repo to my question.

Comment: Yes I notice, I'm more use to debian where it's available by default

Comment: @blarg see the edit, I have another suggestion for you.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the installed size of `dos2unix` is 18K. It has no additional dependencies, affects nothing by itself, and is available in the standard repos. It is a little utility used to convert line endings CRLF to LF.

Answer (score 2):

This should work on anything that is EL5 (CentOS5, RHEL5, etc) or newer.  The package may be on older versions but I haven't checked.  The `mt-st` package for checking tape drive device status is very small and in the `base` repository like you are requesting.

```
[root@testbox ~]# yum info mt-st

Available Packages
Name        : mt-st
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.1
Release     : 5.el6
Size        : 41 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : Tool for controlling tape drives
URL         : ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/system/backup
License     : GPL+
Description : The mt-st package contains the mt and st tape drive management
            : programs. Mt (for magnetic tape drives) and st (for SCSI tape devices)
            : can control rewinding, ejecting, skipping files and blocks and more.
            :
            : Install mt-st if you need a tool to  manage tape drives.
```

Its dependencies are only things that you would be hard-pressed to live without:

```
[root@testbox~]# repoquery --requires --recursive mt-st
/bin/bash
/bin/sh
chkconfig
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)
rtld(GNU_HASH)

[root@testbox~]# repoquery --requires --resolve --recursive mt-st
mt-st-0:1.1-5.el6.x86_64
glibc-0:2.12-1.149.el6.i686
bash-0:4.1.2-29.el6.x86_64
chkconfig-0:1.3.49.3-2.el6_4.1.x86_64
glibc-0:2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Some development package? Those just install header files, which don't do anything unless you try to actively use them.

Some devel packages are quite big though. (E.g., installing the Linux kernel headers is going to be quite big!) Try something like, say, `zlib-devel`?

Answer (score 0):

A documentation package can probably meet your requirements.

An example in Debian:
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/doc/sysadmin-guide

Answer (score -3):

Installing a shell could help. They usually require packages that are already present.

Comment: 'a shell' is a bit broad, several shell already come pre-installed with CentOS, which make those unacceptable to the OP as per point nr. 1.

Comment: That's exactly why I said 'a shell'.
I looked up tcsh.
If that comes pre-packaged, you could try zsh.

Comment: You do not make any sense by saying so, the goal is to install a small package to test yum not a package with dependencies and big footprint on disk